# Multiplying NumPy arrays by scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array of shape `(2,76020,2)`. Basically it is made of two columns containing 76020 rows each, and each row has two entries.

I want to multiply each column by a different weight, say column `1` by `3` and column `2` by `5`. For example:

```
m = 
[3,4][5,8]
[1,2][2,2]

a = [3,5]
```

I want:

```
[9,12][25,40]
[3,6][10,10]
```

I thought I could just multiply m*a, but that gives me instead:

```
[9,20][15,40]
[3,10][6,10]
```

How can I write this multiplication?

Comment: It's a good idea when testing code like this to make the dimensions distinct.  Your test `m` is shape `(2,2,2)`.  Which is the 'column' dimension.  If it was `(3,10,2)` or something else with different dimensions, you'd be able to tell at a glance which axis `a` (with 2 elements) can be applied to (or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem of [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html): you must align the dimensions to multiply, here the second:

```
m = array(
[[[3,4],[5,8]],
[[1,2],[2,2]]])
a = array([3,5])
print(a[None,:,None].shape, m*a[None,:,None])
"""
(1, 2, 1)

[[[ 9 12]
  [25 40]]

 [[ 3  6]
  [10 10]]]
"""
```

Comment: Actually I followed your idea and did m*a[:,None,None] and that worked. So, what is the default if you don't specify anything?

Comment: I think it's a problem of data representation. I give the solution for your example, but perhaps my bracing is not the good. for your (2,76020,2) data, you must of course align on the first dimension, so m*a[:,None,None] is the good solution.

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering what happens if nothing is specified. How does numpy aligns the data by default?

Comment: By default,  alignement is  on the last dim. You can follow the broadcasting link above or http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc for more speaking examples.

Answer (score 2):

As @B.M. says, this is a '[array broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html)' issue.  (The idea behind his answer is correct, but I think his and the OP's dimensions aren't matching up correctly.)

```
>>> m = np.array([[[3,4],[5,8]],[[1,2],[2,2]]])
>>> print(m)
[[[3 4]
  [5 8]]

 [[1 2]
  [2 2]]]
>>> print(m.shape)
(2, 2, 2)
>>> a = np.array([3,5])
>>> print(a.shape)
(2,)
```

We need the shapes of `m` and `a` to match, so we have to 'broadcast' `a` to the correct shape:

```
>>> print(a[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis].shape)
(2, 1, 1)
>>> b = a[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * m
>>> print(b)
[[[ 9 12]
  [15 24]]

 [[ 5 10]
  [10 10]]]
```

In this way the first dimension of `a` is preserved, and maps to each element of the first dimension of `m`.  But there are also two new dimensions ('axes') created to 'broadcast' into the other two dimensions of `m`.

Note: `np.newaxis` is (literally) `None`, they have the same effect.  The former is more readable to understand what's happening.  Additionally, just in terms of standard terminology, the first dimension (axis) is generally referred to as the 'rows', and the second axis the 'columns'.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is ambiguous

> Basically it is made of two columns containing 76020 rows each, and each row has two entries.

In `(2,76020,2)`, which `2` is columns, and which is entries?

I believe your `m` is (that display is also ambiguous)

```
In [8]: m
Out[8]: 
array([[[3, 4],
        [5, 8]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 2]]])


In [9]: m*a
Out[9]: 
array([[[ 9, 20],
        [15, 40]],

       [[ 3, 10],
        [ 6, 10]]])
```

That's the same as `m*a[None,None,:]`.  When broadcasting, numpy automatically adds dimensions at the beginning as needed.  Or iteratively:

```
In [6]: m[:,:,0]*3
Out[6]: 
array([[ 9, 15],
       [ 3,  6]])

In [7]: m[:,:,1]*5
Out[7]: 
array([[20, 40],
       [10, 10]])
```

Since `m` is `(2,2,2)` shape, we can't off hand tell which axis `a` is supposed to multiply.

According to the accepted answer, you want to multiply along the middle axis

```
In [16]: m*a[None,:,None]
Out[16]: 
array([[[ 9, 12],
        [25, 40]],

       [[ 3,  6],
        [10, 10]]])
```

But what if `m` was `(2,3,2)` in shape?  `a` would then have to have 3 values

```
In [17]: m=np.array([[[3,4],[5,8],[0,0]],[[1,2],[2,2],[1,1]]])

In [18]: m*a[None,:,None]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-f631c33646b7> in <module>()
----> 1 m*a[None,:,None]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3,2) (1,2,1)
```

The alternative broadcastings work

```
In [19]: m*a[:,None,None]
Out[19]: 
array([[[ 9, 12],
        [15, 24],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[ 5, 10],
        [10, 10],
        [ 5,  5]]])

In [20]: m*a[None,None,:]
Out[20]: 
array([[[ 9, 20],
        [15, 40],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[ 3, 10],
        [ 6, 10],
        [ 3,  5]]])
```

Now if `m` had distinct dimensions, e.g. `(3,1000,2)`, we could tell at a glance with axis a 2 element weight array would work with.

Comment: The corrected answer is m*a[:,None,None]. I checked that as correct answer because, even though it wasn't, it did teach me how to solve this problem. Thank you too for your answer, though, very exhaustive, and teaching me how to write  better question next time. +1